# Incorrect datetime conversion from UTC after DataSet.GetXml()

Tags: c#, utc, strongly-typed-dataset

My app pulls an object via a web service call, puts it in a typed dataset and sends the `DataSet.GetXml()` to a stored procedure for insert/update on the database.

The problem I'm facing is with two properties of the object : `StartTime`/`EndTime`. The web service sends these in UTC format. Eg. sample `StartTime`-> "2012-11-06T05:00:00Z"
The `DataSet.GetXml()` attempts to convert this UTC value into local time, and my app server is in EST. The resultant value should be reported as "2012-11-06T00:00:00-05:00" but instead it is "2012-11-06T05:00:00-05:00".
The offset value is being added but the time component is not changed.

Is there something incorrect with my understanding here? I'm finding it hard to digest that the `GetXml()` method could have such a bug, and I haven't found anyone else here complain of a similar problem yet.

Here's a stripped down version of the code:

```
public void SaveOrder(int intOrderID)
{
        OrderDataSet objOrderDS = null;
        OrderDataSet.OrdersRow objOrderRow = null;
        ExternHandler handler = null;
        Order objOrder;

        Order objOrder = handler.GetOrder(intOrderID);

        objOrderRow = objOrderDS.Orders.NewOrdersRow();
        objOrderRow.OrderID = objOrder.OrderID;
        objOrderRow.StartTime = objOrder.StartTime;
        objOrderRow.EndTime = objOrder.EndTime;
        objOrderDS.Orders.AddOrdersRow(objOrderRow);

        if (objOrderDS.Orders.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            objOrderDS.Namespace = string.Empty;
            objMappingObjects.Add(new MappingObject("Table", "Orders"));
            objSqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@pOrdersXml", objOrderDS.GetXml()));
            objOrderDS.Clear();
            objOrderDS.Merge(SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigConnectionDB.Trim(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_InsertOrderMetaData", objMappingObjects.ToArray(), objSqlParams.ToArray()));
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reported as"? Can you provide a short but complete program which demonstrates this? (Just creating a hard-coded DataSet should do the job.)

Comment: What I meant by 'reported' was  - I captured the xml data using SQL profiler, and noticed the value there. I'll add the code sample in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the remote machine located where you are returning the data from the Web Service call..? it sounds like a TimeZone Issue to me.. you may want to checkout this know bug / Issue here and they provide a work around as well; if in fact you are having this issue - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842545

Comment: @shashankss: I'd strongly recommend that you take as many other bits of technology out of the equation as possible. Given that you don't need a database in order to create a DataSet, and you don't need a web service in order to generate the XML, you should be able to show all of this in a very small console app.

Comment: @Jon : I'm not sure how to give the code you want. This only occurs with a strongly typed dataset, and I'd have to manually type the code to create that to show the structure?
Also, I'm trying to paste the XMLs related to code added above but the tags are being stripped. I'm confused by the formatting instructions and dont know how to add those.

Comment: input received from web service 

<Order><OrderID>878</OrderID><StartTime>2012-11-06T05:00:00Z</StartTime><EndTime>2012-11-11T04:59:59.997Z</EndTime></Order> 
Dataset.GetXml produces 

<Orders><OrderID>878</OrderID><StartTime>2012-11-06T05:00:00-05:00</StartTime><EndTime>2012-11-11T04:59:59.997-05:00</EndTime></Orders>

Comment: @DJ Kraze : Thanks. The article refers to a situation where dataset object is being 'sent' to a webservice, which is not the case here. Also, the times in soap response are in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found why the UTC-time was being converted to "incorrect local time". The fields 'Startime'/'EndTime' in the typed dataset are of type 'DateTime'. There is a property associated with DataColumn of DateTime type called 'DateTimeMode' which is set to 'UnspecifiedLocal' by default.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datasetdatetime.aspx

Basically, this option adds the offset to the datetime value without converting it. As a test, I changed the 'DateTimeMode' to 'Utc' and retried. The XML received from DataSet.GetXml() was able to convert the value correctly: "2012-11-06T05:00:00Z"

As a solution to my problem, I'm keeping the property to 'UnspecifiedLocal' as it is. Instead, while adding the value to the dataset I convert it to local time.

```
    objOrderRow.EndTime = objOrder.EndTime.ToLocalTime();
```

(Note that this works for me because my app server and database server are in the same timezone and conversion to UTC is uncomplicated.)